# Exceção Jtattoo main

Tags: java, exceção

Boa tarde galera,

Eu e um amigo estamos dando manutenção em um sistema e estamos tentando gerar um jar do sistema. Até ai tudo bem, o sistema compila normal e tudo mais, mas quando nós vamos abrir o arquivo jar gerado ele simplesmente não abre. Fui tentar abrir o jar na prompt de comando do windows e por la eu consegui perceber a existência de uma exceção.

Link do print -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/alet2.jpg

Se alguém puder ajudar eu aprecio muito.

Comment: **Dica**: Coloque o texto da exceção na publicação. Muitos de nós não podem abrir imagens por questões de bloqueios, sem contar que se você colocar o texto fica muito mais fácil de ler. Veja [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](/help/mcve) e [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, o arquivo `.jar` é aberto e o programa inicia, mas, assim como a exceção mostra, não existe nenhuma classe chamada `com.jtattoo.plaf.fast.FastLookAndFeel` nesse arquivo, e como ela provavelmente está sendo usada no `UIManager` para definir o *look and feel*, é uma das primeiras coisas que acontecem na aplicação e, portanto, ela acaba parecendo não estar abrindo.

Se você usa o `Jtattoo` como biblioteca no *Build Path*, caso esteja usando o **Eclipse** existe uma opção para inserir bibliotecas nos arquivos `.jar`, quando você exporta como *"Runnable JAR"*. Se preferir, use **Maven** e não terá que se preocupar com isso se usar o *goal* *"package"*. Há ainda a opção de incluir a classe manualmente no arquivo `.jar`, mas você teria que fazer isso sempre que gerasse um novo arquivo `.jar`, o que não é nada produtivo.